Continous mathematical minimization algorithm / library adaptation
Hopefully this question is not too abstract for SO. If it is, I would appreciate you suggesting where should I post it instead.
In my C# application, I need to run a mathematical optimization algorithm, where control values influences the state of the system, and indirectly changes measured (target) values after the state is updated. For example, there might be 3 (or more) control values which, when changed, affect 3 (or more) target values. Any change to even a single control value may change the values of all 3 target values, and their relationship is not known.
The goal of the algorithm is to find all the minima, where the controls are set to values (while staying within designated limits) that bring the target values within a desired error margin. Later another code will compare them and identify the global minima. In other cases, when it is known that only 1 minima can exist, the optimizer should terminate as soon as it identifies that minima (don't search for additional minimas). Optimization should complete in as few cycles as possible, because changing the state of the system and making measurements is very computationally intensive.
Additionally, I need to have access to the optimizer "guess" data, so it can be re-used for repeated calculations, because the system might change very slightly, and re-using partially fitting data from the previous runs could significantly speed up the process.
The issue is that I can't seem to find a continuous mathematical optimization algorithm or C# library that can be adapted to be used this way.
This is the skeleton code for the Optimizer, and a tester demonstrating how it is intended to be used. The empty Optimizer functions is where I want to plug in the algorithm or library.
public class Optimizer
{
    public List<Control> Controls { get; init; } = new();
    public List<Target> Targets { get; init; } = new();
    public List<Minima> Minimas { get; init; } = new();
    public OptimizerData Data { get; init; } = new();

    public void Optimize()
    {
        //1. Make Controls values guess and assign OptimizedValue value for each object in Controls list
        //2. Save Controls and Targets values combination to Data
        //2. If a minima is found - add it to the list of Minimas
    }

    public bool AllMinimaFound()
    {
        //returns true when there are likely no more minima to be found - used for terminating the optimizer
    }

    public class Control
    {
        public string Name { get; init; }
        public double OptimizedValue { get; set; }
        public double MinBound { get; init; }
        public double MaxBound { get; init; }

        public Control(string name, double minBound, double maxBound)
        {
            Name = name;
            MinBound = minBound;
            MaxBound = maxBound;
        }
    }

    public class Target
    {
        public string Name { get; init; }
        public double MeasuredValue { get; set; }
        public double TargetValue { get; init; }
        public double ErrorMargin { get; init; }

        public Target(string name, double target, double errorMargin)
        {
            Name = name;
            TargetValue = target;
            ErrorMargin = errorMargin;
        }

        public bool IsWithinMargin()
        {
            if (Math.Abs(MeasuredValue - TargetValue) < ErrorMargin) { return true; }
            return false;
        }
    }

    public class Minima
    {
        public Dictionary<string, double> ControlNamesAndValues { get; init; } = new(); // Stores the name and value of each Control for this Minima
    }

    public class OptimizerData
    {
        private List<OptimizerDataPoint> DataPoints { get; init; } = new();

        public void AddDataPoint(List<Control> controls, List<Target> targets)
        {
            DataPoints.Add(new(controls, targets));
        }

        public class OptimizerDataPoint
        {
            public Dictionary<string, double> controlsNamesAndValues { get; init; } = new();
            public Dictionary<string, double> targetsNamesAndValues { get; init; } = new();

            public OptimizerDataPoint(List<Control> controls, List<Target> targets)
            {
                foreach (Control control in controls) { controlsNamesAndValues.Add(control.Name, control.OptimizedValue); }
                foreach (Target target in targets) { targetsNamesAndValues.Add(target.Name, target.MeasuredValue); }
            }
        }
    }
}

public class OptimizerTester
{
    public void OptimizeTest()
    {
        Optimizer optimizer = new();

        optimizer.Controls.Add(new("Length", -5, 5));
        optimizer.Controls.Add(new("Width", 10, 125));
        optimizer.Controls.Add(new("Height", -7, 0));

        optimizer.Targets.Add(new("Mass", 20, 0.01));
        optimizer.Targets.Add(new("SurfaceArea", 32, 0.01));
        optimizer.Targets.Add(new("BoundingBoxVolume", 150, 0.01));

        //test 1 - find all minimas
        while (!optimizer.AllMinimaFound())
        {
            optimizer.Optimize();
            SetMeasuredTargetValues(optimizer.Targets);
        }

        //test2 - find first minima and terminate
        while (optimizer.Minimas.Count < 1)
        {
            optimizer.Optimize();
            SetMeasuredTargetValues(optimizer.Targets);
        }
    }

    public void SetMeasuredTargetValues(List<Optimizer.Target> targets)
    {
        //external code - measures and sets MeasuredValue in each Target
    }
}

Can anyone help me identify the algorithm (or a library if it already exists) to make this work?

Are you asking about library for machine learning? Have a look at ml.net

I think this falls under traditional continuous mathematical optimization link rather than ML. Feel free to correct me if I'm wrong.

This falls under Off-topic: Seeking recommendations for software libraries, tutorials, tools, books, or other off-site resources.

To identify an algorithm, post on https://or.stackexchange.com/ .

Dynamic Programming and convergence; except I don't see any structures that can be iterated other than what is implied in your post ("controls and targets")
